# How to solve the derivative of $b^x$ using the definition

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms, euler-mascheroni-constant

I know that the derivative of $b^x$ is just $b^x \log{(b)}$, and I've seen it being derived using chain rule and such (not that I understand how it's done, I just learned about $e$ today so using the chain rule to derive $b^x$ is outside my scope as of now). In any case I was trying to find out how you could derive $b^x$ using the definition of the derivative, $[f(x+h) - f(x)]/h$. I couldn't find it on the internet so I was wondering if someone here could show me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Actually I think it's $b^x\log(b)$ not $b^x\log(x)$. Does that help?

Comment: Aha, sorry, brain fart lol. And not really I'm afraid.

Comment: I guess you need to show $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{b^h-1}{h}=\log(b)$.  I'm not sure how difficult that is, but I don't think it's trivial.

Comment: How do you define $\log b$ without knowing $e$?

Comment: @celtschk power series? Integral?

Comment: @celtschk Area below the hyperbola, as usual.

Comment: Thinking about it, for this task probably the best way to define it is as $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{b^h-1}{h}$ :-)

Comment: I think the word *solve* in the title is a misuse of that word ...

Answer (score 3):

$$ \frac{d}{dx} b^x = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{b^{x+h}-b^x}{h} = b^x \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{b^h-1}{h}. $$
At this point, you have to evaluate this limit. You have a couple of options here. Obviously L'Hôpital's not going to do. One way is, if your definition of $e^{y}$ is
$$ \exp{y} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{y^k}{k!}, $$
then write $b^h = \exp{(h\log{b})} $, and you can evaluate the limit using the first few terms of the series.

On the other hand, if your definition is
$$ \exp{y} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{y}{n} \right)^n, $$
you have a bit more of a problem. Essentially what this comes down to is the rearrangement
$$ y = \left( 1+\frac{x}{n} \right)^n  \to x = n(y^{1/n}-1) $$
Now, set $h=1/n$ and this looks like your limit, so you conclude that the limit is $\log{b}$. (I would like to see a cleaner version of this, should anyone have one to offer: the rearrangement to get the inverse doesn't look completely justified the way I normally do it.)

And if your definition of $\log{x}$ is an integral, and $\exp{x}$ as its inverse, then you're probably best proving it equivalent to one of the above first...

Comment: Nevermind ... I was just nitpicking.  Or even pettifogging ;)

Comment: @String I for one don't mind those being discreetly edited away by others... still, a good knock to one's ego :-)

Answer (score 1):

So let’s write the problem out using the definition of the derivative:
$$\frac{d}{dx}b^x=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{b^{x+h}-b^x}{h}$$
In the equation above, $b^{x+h}-b^x$ represents a small change in $y$ while $h$ on the denominator represents a small change in $x$. It’s kinda similar to elementary linear algebra.

Now, let's expand $b^{x+h}$ into $b^xb^h$, giving us:
$$\frac{d}{dx}b^x=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{b^xb^h-b^x}{h}$$

Let’s factor the equation on the right in term of $b^x$, which should give us:
$$\frac{d}{dx}b^x=\lim_{h \to 0}b^x(\frac{b^h-1}{h})$$

Let us focus specifically on the $\frac{b^h-1}{h}$ since that’s where all the problems are. So, we just need to figure this out:
$$answer=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{b^h-1}{h}$$

First and foremost, we need to convert $b^h$ into something with the base of the Euler number (it'll make more sense so just bear with me):
$$b^h=e^{({{\log_e}(b)})h}=e^{{\log_e}(b)h}$$

|--- If you know why it can be converted like this, you can skip this section. But to make this understandable to a potential mass of audience who may have diverse mathematical aptitude, I’ll explain it. ---|

So we all know that $2^3=8$.

Also, ${\log_2}(8)=3$

Basically, what the log thing is asking is this: With a base of 2, I need what amount of power to get 8?
$$2^x=8$$
$$x=3$$
$$\Rightarrow{\log_2}(8)=3$$

But, what if you have this:

$$e^{{\log_e}(b)}=?$$

So the first question is with the base of e what is the exponent needed so that you get b?:
$${\log_e}(b)=?$$
$$\Rightarrow{e^?}=b$$
$$\Rightarrow? = an~exponent~when~powered~on~e,~will~give~b$$
$$\Rightarrow{\log_e}(b)=an~exponent~when~powered~on~e,~will~give~b$$
Thus,
$$e^{{\log_e}(b)}=e^{an~exponent~when~powered~on~e,~will~give~b}=b$$

And then you just need to slap on the h exponent because we’re solving for $b^h$ which is how we got:
$$b^h=e^{({{\log_e}(b)})h}=e^{{\log_e}(b)h}$$

|--------------- End ---------------|

After changing $b^h$ with $e^{{\log_e}(b)h}$, we’ll get:
$$answer=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{e^{{\log_e}(b)h}-1}{h}$$

Now, what is $e$?

The number $e$ is special because $\frac{d}{dx}e^x=e^x$. That’s literally the definition of $e$. Anyway, in order to understand what this euler number really is, let’s continue differentiating $e^x$
$$\frac{d}{dx}e^x=?$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}e^x=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{e^{x+h}-e^x}{h}$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}e^x=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{e^xe^h-e^x}{h}$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}e^x=\lim_{h \to 0}e^x(\frac{e^h-1}{h})$$

Since, as established, $\frac{d}{dx}e^x=e^x$. Ergo, $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{e^h-1}{h}$ has to be equal to $1$, lest the derivative of $e^x$ won’t be itself anymore. Now, let’s try to solve for $e$ to find what $e$ is.
$$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{e^h-1}{h}=1$$
$$\lim_{h \to 0}e^h-1=\lim_{h \to 0}h$$
$$\lim_{h \to 0}e^h=\lim_{h \to 0}h+1$$
$$e=\lim_{h \to 0}(h+1)^\frac{1}{h}$$

Ok, let's get back to the original problem.
$$answer=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{e^{{\log_e}(b)h}-1}{h}$$
Now, substituting $e$ with its transformed version as shown above, we’ll get:
$$answer=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{{(h+1)}^{\frac{{\log_e}(b)h}{h}}-1}{h}$$
$$answer=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{{(h+1)}^{{\log_e}(b)}-1}{h}$$

The next step is to expand the expression ${(h+1)}^{{\log_e}(b)}$ using this equation:
$$(x+1)^n=1+nx+\frac{n(n-1)}{2!}x^2+\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!}x^3+...$$
Explaining why this work will probably take too much time and lines so I’m planning to explain this in another thread at another time. For now, you just have to go with it. You can check out this [Veritasium video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gMlf1ELvRzc) in the meantime.

When applying this equation, you’ll get:
$$(h+1)^{{\log_e}(b)}=1+{{\log_e}(b)}h+\frac{{{\log_e}(b)}({{\log_e}(b)}-1)}{2!}h^2+\frac{{{\log_e}(b)}({{\log_e}(b)}-1)({{\log_e}(b)}-2)}{3!}h^3+...$$
Subsituting this back into $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{{(h+1)}^{{\log_e}(b)}-1}{h}$, we'll get:
$$answer=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{1+{{\log_e}(b)}h+\frac{{{\log_e}(b)}({{\log_e}(b)}-1)}{2!}h^2+\frac{{{\log_e}(b)}({{\log_e}(b)}-1)({{\log_e}(b)}-2)}{3!}h^3+...-1}{h}$$
Simplifying time!
$$answer=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{{{\log_e}(b)}h+\frac{{{\log_e}(b)}({{\log_e}(b)}-1)}{2!}h^2+\frac{{{\log_e}(b)}({{\log_e}(b)}-1)({{\log_e}(b)}-2)}{3!}h^3+...}{h}$$
$$answer=\lim_{h \to 0}{{\log_e}(b)}+\frac{{{\log_e}(b)}({{\log_e}(b)}-1)}{2!}h+\frac{{{\log_e}(b)}({{\log_e}(b)}-1)({{\log_e}(b)}-2)}{3!}h^2+...$$
As $\lim_{h \to 0}$, everything becomes $0$, except for ${log_e}(b)$. Hence:
$$answer={{\log_e}(b)}+0+0+...$$
$$answer={\log_e}(b)$$
After all of this, it can finally be concluded that:
$$\frac{d}{dx}b^x={\log_e}(b)b^x$$

Comment: Why are you using $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}b^x$ instead of $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}b^x$? $b$ is being treated as a constant number either way.

Comment: actually, that's a fair point.

Comment: got it fixed. looking for more constructive criticism cuz im new here.

Comment: Use \log to get the better looking $\log$ in place of $log$.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I think I fixed most of them. Can't really be sure if I missed anything.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how one might do it with the definition $\log b = \int_1^b \frac{\mathrm dx}{x}$. However I'm not sure if the exchange of derivative and limit in the first step is allowed.

On one hand we have:
$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm db}\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{b^h-1}{h}
 = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm db}\frac{b^h-1}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{hb^{h-1}}{h} = \frac{1}{b}$$
On the other hand we have:
$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm db}\log b = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm db}\int_1^b\frac{\mathrm dx}{x} = \frac1b$$
Therefore we have
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{b^h-1}{h} = \log b+C$$
To determine $C$ we note that with $b=1$, we have on one hand
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1^h-1}{h} = 0$$
and on the other hand
$$\int_1^1\frac{\mathrm dx}{x} = 0$$
and therefore $C=0$.

Comment: Hang on, how are you interchanging the limits in $d/db$ and $\lim_{h \to 0}$?